# How to obtain a list of cities and countries in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing a clock app for Ubuntu Touch where I am implementing the world clocks feature where the user will be able to select a city from a list and see the local time there. I am using `QTimeZone` and `QDateTime` to get the local time at a city by providing its `timezoneID`. However I am not able to find a Qt library function that might provide me with a list of common cities in the world.

Note: I could always create a local list of cities myself by providing the data in a XML file. The problem with this approach is that I would require the translators to translate that huge list of cities. This is why I am looking more for a inbuilt function that takes care this.

**Is there any such Qt function that would do this?**

Comment: No, there isn't any function in Qt doing that.

Comment: @KeillRandor What would you recommend then? I am sure there are clock app using Qt which display a list of cities. Do they also create their list of cities manually? Or rather can I provide a city name and have a Qt function translate that automatically?

Comment: Search for a list of cities/timezones, download it, use it.

Comment: @KeillRandor yeah that is sort of what I am doing, but it doesn't help with the translation though.  Requesting translators to translate 200+ city names is not ideal :/

Comment: I don't understand the "translation" part. You mean that you want a list of cities in a non-english language? And were you asking if Qt has that?

Comment: @KeillRandor Yeah so if the app is opened in French for instance, the city names would be translated accordingly in french. And yes if there is a qt function for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57837/discussion-between-nik-and-keillrandor).

Comment: How is a noun (city name in this case) language specific?

Comment: @HappyCoder see the PS in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of selection of timezones, if you could settle with listing only representative major cities for each timezone (i.e. 80+ cities, rather than 200+ of them), you may take reference from the settings app under the Android Project.  In the following directory -

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-2.3.2_r1/res

Under each `xml-[language code]` folder, there are files named `timezones.xml`, listing out major representative cities in each timezone in the respective language, with the corresponding timezone ID.

(The English names are listed under `xml/timezones.xml`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in Qt. However you can work around this problem by using an API by some map provider such as **Google Maps**, **OpenStreetMap** etc. For the second I'm 100% sure that it has an API for C++. You can get a list of cities in your language and try to use the API. Most (all?) public map providers provide translation for the names of countries and cities (Note: city != village with 300 inhabitants) so you can just change the locale setting and that should do the trick. In order to prevent language mishaps I suggest that you use some language-neutral routine internally such as GPS coordinates or similar. It all comes down to the way the map provider's database is structured but I think we can say with a high degree of confidence that name tag, GPS coordinates and - who knows - maybe even timezone are present.

**PS:** @HappyCoder, yes there is sometime a HUGE difference in the naming of both cities/towns/villages and countries. Even in the countries where Latin alphabet is used you can see it:

- Germany (English)
- Alemania (Spanish)
- Deutschland (German)
- L'Allemagne (French)
- Duitsland (Afrikaans)
- ...

Same applies to cities. And it gets even worse if you add Cyrillic, Greek, Chinese, Arabic etc. to the mix.